# Brother J430W network driver

Tags: brother

I am hoping someone can help me.  I am a former Microsoft user who has, in the last few weeks, installed Linux Ubuntu 16.04 on both a desktop (32 bit) and a laptop (64 bit).  I have a Brother MFC-J430W printer that both computers need to connect to via network.

I have been researching for days.  I have tried the advice in this article:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1999216

...but it is way too advanced for me.

I have tried the advice in this article:
http://tutorialforlinux.com/2015/06/20/how-to-install-brother-mfc-j430w-printer-drivers-quickstart-scanning-on-ubuntu-linux-gnu-easy-guide/
...but it did not work.  These steps never even took me to an install.

None of the other threads have been easy enough for me to understand.  I need to stress again, I am a NEW USER.  I didn't even know what the "terminal" was until I spoke to a local tech guy in our area.  He is even unable to help me accomplish this.

I have been to the Brother website but it is like reading Greek.  I don't even know whether I want the (rpm) or (deb) file.  I do not know what a "CUPS" file is, or what an "LDR" is.  I am sure you get the picture.

I need step-by-step instructions that assume little, if any, knowledge of the inner workings of Ubuntu.  I can follow instructions if they are detailed.  I know how to get to my terminal, but that's about it!  I bought a book on how to use the terminal in Linux, but it is way beyond me!  I have never done anything related to command prompts in my computer use history.

Thanks so much for your help.  It is very appreciated!

---

```
root@Paul-Inspiron:/home/paul/Downloads# chmod 755 linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1 
root@Paul-Inspiron:/home/paul/Downloads# ^C 
root@Paul-Inspiron:/home/paul/Downloads# bash linux-brprinter-installer
Brother MFC-J430W Driver-packages cannot be found. 
Confirm the model name.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Ubuntu uses .DEB.
- CUPS is the printer server.
- LPR (not LDR) is a command that prints files.

> I  need step-by-step instructions that assume little, if any, knowledge of the inner workings of Ubuntu.

The link seems pretty clear.

- download the file from the site named "Driver Install Tool". Save it in the "~/Downloads` directory.
- open a terminal (press the super key, search for terminal and execute it. You will see a screen with a $ in it and a prompt). Type `cd ~/Downloads`.
- make it executable:

  ```
  $ls -ltr
  -r-------- 1 rinzwind rinzwind 92056 jun 20 20:50 linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1
  $ chmod 755 linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1 
  $ ls -ltr
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 rinzwind rinzwind 92056 jun 20 20:50 linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1
  ```
- Execute it with `sudo ./linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1`  and follow the onscreen questions (the script is a text file and seems to look for an installation of cups and some other things, it also asks for model name).

---

edit:

```
$ sudo ./linux-brprinter-installer-2.0.0-1  
[sudo] password for rinzwind: 
Input model name ->
```

Your model name should be `MFX-J430W`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41476/discussion-on-answer-by-rinzwind-brother-j430w-network-driver).